# How to shutdown Remote PC using C#.net?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, system-shutdown

I wanted my application to shutdown the remote PC on a button click event. How can i achieve such heights?

I don't want to use telnet or any process to occur in the remote computer. Please guide me in C#.net programming interface.

Comment: Please take a look at sysinternals: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062 the executable that you are looking for can be this: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897541

Comment: I think it is hard to achieve this using managed code by the way

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to call the Win32 API. Take a look to [InitiateSystemShutdowEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376874%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

If you never worked with interop, here you have the code to call this method from .NET. [InitiateSystemShutdownEx PInvoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/advapi32/InitiateSystemShutdownEx.html)

However, take into account that you will need some elevated privileges...

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way will be to call the [shutdown](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/shutdown.mspx?mfr=true) command with the appropriate parameters.